HttpClient call to Auvik web API returns unauthorized
Final Edit (solution): Even though the documentation for Auvik says that the schema is HTTP, I had to change my URL to HTTPS. Because I saw a 301 with a location using HTTPS, I figured this was a good place to start. That, however, by itself didn't fix my problem. In my desire to make adding endpoints with URL parameters, I added a "/" to the end of all the end points. I erroneously figured this trialing backslash would be ignored if nothing followed it. When I combined using HTTPS with removing the trailing backslash, it worked. Hopefully, someone out there will find this useful.
Edit: It appears that my problem is that the HttpClient is working as intended. When I make the initial HTTP call to the Auvik API, I am given a 301 Permanently Moved response and a redirect to an HTTPS end point. When that redirect happens, the HttpClient removes the authentication header hence the "Unauthorized" response. I was able to see this happen using the Postman Proxy and inspecting the calls from Postman vs the calls from C#.
I am using the following code to access the Auvik web API for devices on our network. I am using credentials that, in Postman, are working just fine with a 200 Ok response. When I use the same credentials in my C# code, I get 401 Unauthorized. I have tried to use WireShark to look at the requests and they look nearly identical (the non-identical headers like Postman-Token, are required).
protected async Task<HttpClient> GetHttpClientAsync(int timeout)
{
    var name = await _Secrets.GetSecretAsync(_CK_API_USER);//_Secrets is a protected IReadOnlySecretService (custom code) to retrieve secret values
    var token = await _Secrets.GetSecretAsync(_CK_API_KEY);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The secret service must contain valid secret values for the following keys: [{_CK_API_USER}], [{_CK_API_KEY}].");
    }

    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseUrl), Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout) };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(name, token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    return client;
}


I'm not really sure what to do at this point. The blocked out parts are identical, so everything tells me that the requests should yield the same results, yet here we are. Any suggestions?
For additional context, I am including a screen shot of my Postman call and the C# call using Postman generated C# code (which also returned Unauthorized). Added another screenshot with one of the responses to my question (401 result):
Success:

Failure:



Try this code. I've modified the basic authentication code a bit. I hope it works for you.
protected async Task<HttpClient> GetHttpClientAsync(int timeout)
{
    var name = await _Secrets.GetSecretAsync(_CK_API_USER);
    var token = await _Secrets.GetSecretAsync(_CK_API_KEY);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The secret service must contain valid secret values for the following keys: [{_CK_API_USER}], [{_CK_API_KEY}].");
    }

    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_BaseUrl), Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout) };

    //Set up Basic Authentication
    string encodedCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{name}:{token}"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedCredentials);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    return client;
}


I copied this and pasted it into my unit test, with my credentials, and it failed to get an Ok response. The simple fact that everyone is looking at this request and thinks the same thing I do (that there is an issue with the string value for the credentials) leads me to believe that the issue doesn't lie with how the end point is being called, but rather in the way that the request is put together (i.e. there is something missing or something messed up with the credentials).

Even though this didn't solve my problem, I am awarding it the 50 rep because it is the most complete answer. My problem, it appears, is that the end point that Auvik gives through their documentation is an HTTP call yet when I make that call I get a 301 Permanently Moved response and when that happens my Authentication header gets dropped before redirecting to the HTTPS end point (the documentation doesn't say anything about using HTTPS).

var authenticationCredentials = $"{name}:{password}"; -- your token
var base64EncodedAuthenticationCredentials  = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationCredentials ));


requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationCredentials );
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

This is standard type of basic authorization request. Check your credentials values.
Also, you can try to use the Web debugging proxy tool like Feddler classic in order to compare your requests.

I figured it was my credentials, too, but I checked the Base 64 conversion value against what Postman has for that value and it is the same so I'm 100% sure that the credentials in my C# are the same that I put into Postman (which gave me a 200 Ok). I also believe this to be a "standard type of basic authorization request", which is why I am so confused as to why I am getting a 401-Unauthorized.

I'm rather unexperienced but I noticed you only clear your Accept-Header but do not fill it again. Might this be a problem?
I did something like this in one of my projects and it worked:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string URL = $"{BaseURL}{endpoint}";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "TestHttpClient");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");

var AuthByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(AuthByteArray));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL);

The "*/*" means it will accept anything, so you should probably not use it. But you could use it for testing.
Some links I thought might help:
https://gist.github.com/dfch/7b338046d5e63e3b3106
Something I remembered after posting: I used Insomnia for testing and it doesn't show the Accept-Header in the headers-tab but it does in the timeline tab, maybe you can check that in Postman too.

That was my first thought too, that I was missing some header information. When I made the call in Postman, I narrowed it down to only the ones which were required (tested by removing those headers in Postman). I had also used the Convert class to do the base 64 conversion initially, but it gave me the same result (i.e. Unauthorized). I appreciate the reply, though.
